# Prevent GIF characters from displaying onscreen

Tags: php

I have this nice bit of code that generates a gif on the fly, where I place text over an existing image:

```
<?
$pic_name = "test.gif";

$gif_image = imagecreatefromgif('background.gif');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($gif_image, 0, 0, 0);
     $font_path = 'arial.ttf';
      $text = "E-Signed By:";
      imagettftext($gif_image, 6, 0, 72, 11, $text_color, $font_path, $text);

      imagegif($gif_image);
      imagegif($gif_image, $pic_name);
      imagedestroy($gif_image);

?>
```

When I am done creating the image, I redirect to the next page:

```
echo 

"<html>
<head>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='0; url=https://emortgagecapital.com/mlo/agreement.php'>

</head>
</html>";
```

The glitch is, on the redirect, for only a moment, I see a very long string of the GIF special characters, that looks something like this:

```
GIF87aR�9Z�9c�Bc�Jk�Rs�Z{�k��s��{�����
```

There is a lot more, but you get the idea.

Now, if I leave this bit of code in, the special characters don't display, but it kills the further execution of the script, and simply displays the image on screen:

```
header('Content-type: image/gif');
```

I tried placing the redirect as the header, but then the image never rendered and did not save to the server - the main reason for the script.

How do I run this script, and redirect, so the special characters do not 'flash' on the screen?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually *trying* to do. So you create an image on the fly... and then the split second that you create it you redirect the user? Won't the user be unable to see the image in that situation, making the creation of the image pointless? Also, don't `echo` out `<html>` / `<head>` tags -- simply use `header("Location: ... ")` to redirect.

Comment: Good question. I am creating a signature image that is placed on a pdf the code loops back to; it is supposed to happen in the background.

Comment: `imagegif($gif_image, $pic_name);` makes sensw creating the file, the other call to `imagegif` does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[imagegif — Output image to browser or file](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php)

`imagegif($gif_image);`

your writing to the screen for no reason, just remove the line